# Remove all tags from string except a certain regex

Tags: php, regex, strip-tags

I've written [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/ulTxs9/4) :

```
<span class="icon(.*?)><\/span>
```

And I've got this string :

```
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 1em;">Text 1 <span style="font-weight: bold;">TEXT 2</span><span style="color: #e67e23; font-size: 1.2em;"><span class="icon x-small icon-play"></span>&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #e03e2d;">Text 3</span> <span style="color: #a68965;">Text 4 </span></span><span style="font-size: 0.7em; color: #000000;">Text 5</span></p>
```

And I would like to remove all tags from that string except the tag resulting from the regex above. So I would get this final result :

```
Text 1 Text 2<span class="icon x-small icon-play"></span>&nbsp;Text 3 Text 4 Text 5
```

As you can see in this output, all tags have been cleared except the tag I'm looking for.

I took a look at PHP's [`strip_tags`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) but unfortunately they do not take a regex as a second parameter, thus not doing what I'm looking for. I tried doing it with a [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) but I was not able to create such a complex regex.

Any idea on what's the best way of doing this either it is with regex or not?

Comment: You may need to split the string on `<span class="icon(.*?)><\/span>`, then replace the tags in each part and join back again with `<span class="icon(.*?)><\/span>`

Comment: @Theo good workaround I was going to use if I had no answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
preg_replace('/<span class="icon.*?><\/span>(*SKIP)(*F)|<[^<>]+>/', '', $string)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/ecbPWM/2)

The expression will find `<span class="icon....></span>` strings to ignore them with `(*SKIP)(*F)` and then all other tags will be removed (matched with `<[^<>]+>`).

Comment: Ingenious, thank you! Didn't know the existence of `(*SKIP)`.